# How can I set the height of a WPF-Control to the maximum which is available?

Tags: wpf, controls, height

For example: I have a Stackpanel with height of 200px. In this panel a grid with a height of 50px. How can I add a control (for example a textblock), which use the complete rest of height (150px) and not only the height of the textfont?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `DockPanel` instead. The last item added to a `DockPanel` takes up remaining space.